# DOMDocument->saveHTML() vs urlencode with commercial at symbol (@)

Tags: php, domdocument, encode, urlencode, rfc

Using [`DOMDocument()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), I'm replacing links in a `$message` and adding some things, like `[@MERGEID]`. When I save the changes with [`$dom_document->saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php), the links get "sort of" url-encoded. `[@MERGEID]` becomes `%5B@MERGEID%5D`.

Later in my code I need to replace `[@MERGEID]` with an ID. So I search for `urlencode('[@MERGEID]')` - however, [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) changes the commercial at symbol (@)  to %40, while saveHTML() has left it alone. So there is no match - `'%5B@MERGEID%5D' != '%5B%40MERGEID%5D'`

Now, I know can run `str_replace('%40', '@', urlencode('[@MERGEID]'))` to get what I need to locate the merge variable in $message.

**My question is**, what RFC spec is DOMDocument using, and why is it different than urlencode or even rawurlencode? Is there anything I can do about that to save a str_replace?

Demo code:

```
$message = '<a href="http://www.google.com?ref=abc" data-tag="thebottomlink">Google</a>';
$dom_document = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Supress content errors
$dom_document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));       
$elements = $dom_document->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($elements as $element) {    
    $link = $element->getAttribute('href'); //http://www.google.com?ref=abc
    $tag = $element->getAttribute('data-tag'); //thebottomlink
    if ($link) {
        $newlink = 'http://www.example.com/click/[@MERGEID]?url=' . $link;
        if ($tag) {
            $newlink .= '&tag=' . $tag;
        } 
        $element->setAttribute('href', $newlink);
    }
}
$message = $dom_document->saveHTML();
$urlencodedmerge = urlencode('[@MERGEID]');
die($message . ' and url encoded version: ' . $urlencodedmerge); 
//<a data-tag="thebottomlink" href="http://www.example.com/click/%5B@MERGEID%5D?url=http://www.google.com?ref=abc&amp;tag=thebottomlink">Google</a> and url encoded version: %5B%40MERGEID%5D
```

Comment: This is of interest to me as well.  Have you tried using utf8_encode/decode or iconv per the manual?

Comment: @Kkinsey Run utf8_encode/decode or iconv on what?

Comment: Nevermind.  Mistake on my part, I think.  I'll look again.

Comment: To paraphrase the question: Why is the character `@` not percent-encoded in the value of a `DOMAttribute` node when using `DOMDocument::saveHTML`?

Comment: Would it not make sense to just urlencode the original [@mergeid] whan saving it in the first place as well? Your search should then match without the need for the str_replace?
$newlink = 'http://www.example.com/click/'.urlencode('[@MERGEID]').'?url=' . $link;

Comment: @GavinSimpson The problem is that the code being passed in, `$message`, is a user-generated template. So they can write their own template, with their own code.

Comment: First off thanks for the tip, and making feel stupid once again :)     '$dom_document->loadHTML(utf8_decode(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')));' will leave both outputs as '%5B%40MERGEID%5D'. Would that help?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that those two encoding serve different purposes. `urlencode()` encodes ["a string to be used *in a query part* of a URL"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), while `$element->setAttribute('href', $newlink);` encodes a complete URL to be used as an URL.

For example:

```
urlencode('http://www.google.com'); // -> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

This is convenient for encoding *the query part*, but it cannot be used on `<a href='...'>`.

However:

```
$element->setAttribute('href', $newlink); // -> http://www.google.com
```

will properly encode the string so that it is still usable in `href`. The reason that it cannot encode `@` because it cannot tell whether `@` is a part of the query or is it part of the `userinfo` or `email` url (for example: `mailto:invisal@google.com` or `invisal@127.0.0.1`)

---

### Solution

1. Instead of using `[@MERGEID]`, you can use `@@MERGEID@@`. Then, you replace that with your ID later. This solution does not require you to even use `urlencode`.
2. If you insist to use `urlencode`, you can just use %40 instead of @. So, your code will be like this `$newlink = 'http://www.example.com/click/[%40MERGEID]?url=' . $link;`
3. You can also do something like `$newlink = 'http://www.example.com/click/' . urlencode('[@MERGEID]') . '?url=' . $link;`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Phil, he asked why those two produce different result when encode `[@MERGEID]`

Comment: @invisal I understand what you're saying. So, given that explanation, there isn't really a way around having to run my extra `str_replace`?

Comment: @John, YES and NO, check my solution section.

Comment: 1, 2, and 3 are all possible solutions for the problem posed in my question, thanks! Unfortunately none of them will work for my own real world problem - the merge variables are inserted by a front-end user, and have been for some time now, so a change from what they know isn't totally possible right now. 2 & 3 won't work because many of the links are already created inside of `$message` so I don't have access to split them up like I do `$newlink`.

Answer (score 3):

`urlencode` function and `rawurlencode` are mostly based on `RFC 1738`. However, since 2005 the current RFC in use for URIs standard is `RFC 3986`.

On the other hand, The DOM extension uses UTF-8 encoding, which is based on [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) . Use utf8_encode() and utf8_decode() to work with texts in ISO-8859-1 encoding or Iconv for other encodings.

> The generic URI syntax mandates that new URI schemes that provide for
> the representation of character data in a URI must, in effect,
> represent characters from the unreserved set without translation, and
> should convert all other characters to bytes according to UTF-8, and
> then percent-encode those values.

Here is a function to decode URLs according to `RFC 3986`.

```
<?php
    function myUrlEncode($string) {
       $entities = array('%21', '%2A', '%27', '%28', '%29', '%3B', '%3A', '%40', '%26', '%3D', '%2B', '%24', '%2C', '%2F', '%3F', '%25', '%23', '%5B', '%5D');
       $replacements = array('!', '*', "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "%", "#", "[", "]");
       return str_replace($entities, $replacements, urldecode($string));
    }
?>
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/9tkr-ipu6).

---

**Update:**
Since UTF8 has been used to encode `$message`:

```
$dom_document->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'))
```

Use `urldecode($message)` when returning the URL without percents.

```
die(urldecode($message) . ' and url encoded version: ' . $urlencodedmerge);
```

Comment: Why haven't `urlencode` and `rawurlencode` been updated to use the url standard RFC?

Comment: It seems there were other accepted ways of doing URL encoding in the past.

Comment: But, is running `urldecode` any different in resources or time than running `str_replace`?

Comment: It is my understanding that under the hood they both use regular expressions. A quick test shows no relevant difference.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem [has been very well explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27350360/1446005) from a technical point of view.

In my opinion, however, there is a conceptual flaw in your approach, and it *created* the situation that you are now trying to fix.

By processing your input `$message` through a DomDocument object, you have moved to a higher level of abstraction. It is wrong to manipulate as a unique plain string something that has been "promoted" to a HTML stream.

Instead of trying to reproduce DomDocument's behaviour, use the library itself to locate, extract and replace the values of interest:

```
$token = 'blah blah [@MERGEID]';
$message = '<a id="' . $token . '" href="' . $token . '"></a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($message);
echo $dom->saveHTML(); // now we have an abstract HTML document

// extract a raw value
$rawstring = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
// do the low-level fiddling
$newstring = str_replace($token, 'replaced', $rawstring);
// push the new value back into the abstract black box.
$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute('href', $newstring);

// less code written, but works all the time
$rawstring = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('id');
$newstring = str_replace($token, 'replaced', $rawstring);
$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute('id', $newstring);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

As illustrated above, today we are trying to fix the problem when your token is inside a href, but one day we may want to search and replace the tag elsewhere in the document. To account for this case, do not bother making your low-level code HTML-aware.

(an alternative option would be not loading a DomDocument until all low-level replacements are done, but I am guessing this is not practical)

---

Complete proof of concept:

```
function searchAndReplace(DOMNode $node, $search, $replace) {
    if($node->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attribute) {
            $input = $attribute->nodeValue;
            $output = str_replace($search, $replace, $input);
            $attribute->nodeValue = $output;
        }
    }

    if(!$node instanceof DOMElement) { // this test needs double-checking
        $input = $node->nodeValue;
        $output = str_replace($search, $replace, $input);
        $node->nodeValue = $output;
    }

    if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
            searchAndReplace($child, $search, $replace);
        }
    }
}

$token = '<>&;[@MERGEID]';
$message = '<a/>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($message);

$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute('id', "foo$token");
$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute('href', "http://foo@$token");
$textNode = new DOMText("foo$token");
$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->appendchild($textNode);

echo $dom->saveHTML();

searchAndReplace($dom, $token, '*replaced*');

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `saveXML()` it won't mess with the encoding the way `saveHTML()` does:

**PHP**

```
//your code...
$message = $dom_document->saveXML();
```

*EDIT*: also remove the XML tag:

```
//this will add an xml tag, so just remove it
$message=preg_replace("/\<\?xml(.*?)\?\>/","",$message);

echo $message;
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><a href="http://www.example.com/click/[@MERGEID]?url=http://www.google.com?ref=abc&amp;tag=thebottomlink" data-tag="thebottomlink">Google</a></body></html>
```

Notice that both still correctly convert `&` to `&amp;`

Comment: Since it's actually an HTML document, what ramifications will running `saveXML` have?

Comment: saveXML will output an xhtml document, and will also stick the `<?xml` line on top. Additionally, it will use hex encodings for certain characters where `saveHTML` might use entity encodings, e.g., `&copy;` becomes `&#xA9;`

Comment: Sounds like it's not really a solution then hot an HTML document

Comment: i don't know what you mean

Comment: then for a HTML document* - sorry, typo. Saving HTML as XML, and adding XML declaration tags isn't valid at all - put your output through the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and look at the output. So, this isn't a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not make sense to just urlencode the original [@mergeid] whan saving it in the first place as well? Your search should then match without the need for the str_replace?

```
$newlink = 'http://www.example.com/click/'.urlencode('[@MERGEID]').'?url=' . $link;
```

I know this does not answer the first post of the question, but you cannot post code in comments as far as I can tell.

Comment: You can post code in the comments - when adding a comment, off the bottom right corner of the textarea is [a "help" link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) :) Simply use a backtick.